# How to implement Queue in Java?

Tags: java

I have a folder with 1 `ThMapInfratab1-2.exe` file and 3 `.txt` files. If you run `.exe` file in any way(through command prompt,just double click and through any language) one Icon will be appear on `Taskbar`.

[image]

My `.exe` will be run 2-3 minutes.

Know I want to run these `.exe` file using `Java`.I found How to run `.exe` from `Java` technology.

My concept was, first I will find `.txt` file Names from the directory.finally I will get like this.

```
List<File> fileNames={"File1.txt","File2.txt","File3.txt"};
```

Know I want to run my `.exe` file 3 times because my `fileNames` length is equals to `3`.For this I wrote the following code.

```
 //ExeFileProcess Function

 public void ExeternalFileProcessing(String DirectoryPath,String exeFileName,String inputFileName) throws IOException
 {
     String executableFileName = DirectoryPath+"/"+exeFileName;
     String inputFile=inputFileName;
     ProcessBuilder processBuilderObject=new ProcessBuilder(executableFileName,inputFile);
     File absoluteDirectory = new File(DirectoryPath);
     processBuilderObject.directory(absoluteDirectory);
     processBuilderObject.start();
     //processBuilderObject.wait();
 }

//Main Function code.

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
     ExternalFileExecutions ExternalFileExecutionsObject=new ExternalFileExecutions();
     for (int fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < fileNames.size(); fileIndex++) 
     {
         ExternalFileExecutionsObject.ExeternalFileProcessing("C:/Users/Infratab Bangalore/Desktop/Rod","ThMapInfratab1-2.exe",fileNames[fileIndex ]);
     }
 }
```

I evaluated above code, at a time 3 `.exe` processes are started.But I don't want like that. I want to run `.exe` file one by one(we need to monitor, whether the previous `.exe` process was done or not. once it's done it allows to next Iteration).

I tried with `Wait()`.but it's not working.

I guess, for this I need to add some code in my `ExeternalFileProcessing()`. But I didn't get anything.

can anyone suggest me.

I hope, you understand, what My problem.

Comment: you are asking a lot of questions... are we coding your product?! :-p

Comment: @PhilippSander Actually I have only one problem,but I want to learn `Java`.so I divided my problem into function wise and I am trying to figure it out. But in every function I stuck in somewhere, I am asking help from `StackoverFlow` guys.because these guys are ready to help to anyone(even for starting guys). Finally I reached final stage of my problem. for this I am working from yesterday. because everytime, I don't want to base on any one. so first I am trying using Google, If I face any problem I am posting question in `StackoverFlow`.

Comment: truly firend it was no offense or anything! but if you're trying to learn jave i would recommend something simpler for the start

Answer (score 2):

`ProcessBuilder.start` method returns an instance of `Process` class. YOu can use [waitFor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) method to wait until created process stops:

```
    ...
    Process process = processBuilderObject.start();
    process.waitFor();
}
```

`processBuilderObject.wait()` is a invocation of Object's [wait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) method. It is used for concurrency and doesn't relate to processes at all.

Comment: It's working great. I didn't understand one thing in your code. 
`Process process = processBuilderObject.start();`.What is `Process(First Word)` and `process(second word)` from above line. may be it's very question but I am new to Java side. so can you explain.

Comment: @urtrulyfriend first `Process` is a type of variable and second `process` is a variable's name.

Comment: Some times My `.exe` is taking 20-30 min for running,because The Evaluation time process was based on `.txt`file. In this cases next for loop iteration also starting before stopping the previous `.exe` file execution.If the `.txt` size is small then `.exe` taking 2-3 min.this time working perfectly.But not working in case1(`.txt` size is big).